# What identifier should I add for this optional?

Tags: swift, core-data, swift2, mapkit

I want to add this optional

```
var mapRegion : MKCoordinateRegion
```

It gives me an error that I need an identifier next to class:

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate,
```

What's that identifier?

The file looks like this:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData
import MapKit

class TableViewController: UITableViewController, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate,  {

let moc = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
var frc : NSFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController()

var mapRegion : MKCoordinateRegion


func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest {

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Item")
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name",
                                          ascending: true)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
    return fetchRequest
}
func getFRC() -> NSFetchedResultsController {

    frc = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest(), managedObjectContext: moc, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
    return frc
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    frc = getFRC()
    frc.delegate = self

    do {
        try frc.performFetch()
    } catch {
        print("Failed to perform initial fetch.")
        return
    }

    self.tableView.rowHeight = 480
    self.tableView.backgroundView = UIImageView( image: UIImage(named: "flatgrey2"))
    self .tableView.reloadData()
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    frc = getFRC()
    frc.delegate = self

    do {
        try frc.performFetch()
    } catch {
        print("Failed to perform initial fetch.")
        return
    }
    self .tableView.reloadData()
}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source


override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    let numberOfSections = frc.sections?.count
    return numberOfSections!

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    let numberofRowsInSection = frc.sections?[section].numberOfObjects

    return numberofRowsInSection!

    //return 0

}



override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    if indexPath.row % 2 == 0 {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    } else {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.2)
        cell.textLabel?.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.0)
        cell.detailTextLabel?.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.0)
    }


    // Configure the cell...
    cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()
    cell.detailTextLabel?.textColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()

    let item = frc.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! Item
    cell.textLabel?.text = item.name
    cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(data: (item.image)!)

    return cell
}





/*
// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    // Return false if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return true
}
*/


// Override to support editing the table view.

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let managedObject : NSManagedObject = frc.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! NSManagedObject
    moc.deleteObject(managedObject)

    do {
        try moc.save()
    } catch {
        print ("Failed to save.")
        return
    }
}

func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: NSIndexPath?) {
    tableView.reloadData()
}






/*
// Override to support rearranging the table view.
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, moveRowAtIndexPath fromIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {

}
*/

/*
// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    // Return false if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return true
}
*/


// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    if segue.identifier == "edit" {

        let cell = sender as! UITableViewCell
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(cell)
        let itemController : AddEditVC = segue.destinationViewController as! AddEditVC
        let item : Item = frc.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath!)  as! Item
        itemController.item = item
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have declared `var mapRegion : MKCoordinateRegion` but don't have any initializers or default value. To make it an optional, just add `?` to it, so declare:

```
var mapRegion : MKCoordinateRegion?
```

Answer (score 1):

The variable should have a value when it is declared otherwise it will show this error. Assign a value to your variable `var mapRegion : MKCoordinateRegion`. If the value is given at a later stage i.e., if it depends on any calculations then make it an optional like this `var mapRegion : MKCoordinateRegion?` But you have to unwrap the variable whenever you want to use **mapRegion** value by placing an exclamation mark at the end of the variable name.